# amsmath - Unable to properly define \@@leqno. primitive \leqno no longer primitive

Tags: amsmath

I am using MikTeX and I have suddenly started to get a problem with amsmath. I have managed to reduce it to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get the message:

> `Unable to properly define \@@leqno. primitive \leqno no longer primitive\@saveprimitive\eqno\@@eqno`

I have recently updated MikTeX and I am using amsmath v2.17o.

If I comment out the `\usepackage{amsmath}` the file compiles without any error message.

Comment: you have a new latex but an old amsmath,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle do you mean the other way around? v2.17o is the latest version of amsmath.

Comment: Original Poster: can you edit your question to include a copy of the logs? It should be in `<filename>.log`. Post at least the first 50 lines or so, so we can see what the various package versions are according to the latex compiler.

Comment: @WillieWong no the latest version of amsmath can not give that message. OP: Did you update miktex in user and admin modes?

Comment: `% \changes{v2.17o}{2023/05/13}{Do not error if \cs{eqno} not primitive (gh/1059)}`

Comment: Thanks to the suggestion to look lower down in the log file I have found the problem! I have style files for various Journals, each in a separate folder, and one of the style files came with the ams style files. These are loaded after the ams style files in the default folder, and of course are not updated when I update the packages. I have removed them and the problem has disappeared.

Comment: If you want to self answer (naming and shaming the journal:-) it may help others in same position, or we could just close as a "local installation problem", whichever you think best.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed a conflict between a new version of latex and an old version of amsmath. By looking in the log file I found that MikTeX was also loading old versions of the amsmath style files that had been provided with the style file of a journal, and which were stored in a local folder (....\TeX\texmf\tex\latex...). These were, of course, not updated when the packages were updated, and because they are stored locally they are loaded after the packages in the default folder, replacing the updated versions. I have removed these old versions and this has solved the problem.